# is there a "Textmerge"-function for php?

Tags: php, merge

reading a Blob from a database containing some text, i.e. a contract, to fill with variable data. The data from db is something like this:

```
"Bla bla <<Name>> Bla, Bla, <<Date>> BlaBla .... "
```

now i want to

```
    $contract = merge( $rec['contract'], '<<','>>' array('Name' =>'Smith','Date'=>'2018-08-08'));
```

Had i really to write it myself?

I know about "eval" and double-quotes and str_replace() to loop on the array, but i would end up with about 150 loops...

Comment: why do you need 150 loops?

Comment: Would you be better off using some form of template system (I've only used Twig).

Comment: You can use `preg_replace_callback()` to implement this. Match the regexp `<<(\w+)>>`, then look up the capture group value in the array.

Answer (score 4):

`str_replace()` can accept an array of strings to be replaced.  This might be your best bet.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
 $contract = "Bla bla <<Name>> Bla, Bla, <<Date>> BlaBla .... ";
 $contract = str_replace(['<<Name>>', '<<Date>>'], ['Joel', 'August, 8'], $contract);
 echo $contract;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple template function I just wrote that uses preg_replace_callback and zero loops (internally php will loop, but this code itself doesn't):

```
<?php

function merge($template, $open, $close, $data){
    // Escape the open and close tags
    $open = preg_quote($open, '/');
    $close = preg_quote($close, '/');

    // Find the template strings and replace with data from our
    // $data array where the key exists.
    return preg_replace_callback(
        "/{$open}(.*?){$close}/",
        function($matches) use ($data){
            // If the key exists in $data, return that as replacement
            if(array_key_exists($matches[1], $data)){
                return $data[$matches[1]];
            } else {
                // If the key doesn't exist, return the tag back so no replacement.
                return $matches[0];
            }
        }, $template);
}

$template = "Bla bla <<Name>> Bla, Bla, <<Date>> BlaBla .... ";
$data = array('Name' =>'Smith','Date'=>'2018-08-08');

var_dump($template);
var_dump(merge($template, "<<", ">>", $data));
```

Outputs:

```
string(48) "Bla bla <<Name>> Bla, Bla, <<Date>> BlaBla .... "
string(47) "Bla bla Smith Bla, Bla, 2018-08-08 BlaBla .... "
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/JHAPo